# Lightweight python modules to convert LAS data formats to text formats?

Tags: python, convert, lidar, ascii, las

I searched on the net and found pyLAS, but it seems to require quite a few other modules and I couldn't get the install right.

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

What about the [liblas](http://liblas.org/index.html) [Python API](http://liblas.org/tutorial/python.html) (not sure how lightweight this is though)?

```
>>> from liblas import file
>>> f = file.File('file.las',mode='r')
>>> for p in f:
...     print 'X,Y,Z: ', p.x, p.y, p.z
```

Answer (score 4):

What about [PDAL](http://www.pdal.io/)? There is a Python package here - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PDAL/1.2.0.

Here is an example from the command line documentation:

```
pdal translate input.las output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

laspy and pylas have merged and now there is [Laspy 2.0](https://laspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This library has been very useful to me for several workflows like reclassification of points (Vegetation, water and infrastructure identification).